# Clearing ISupportIncrementalLoading

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have created a search page in a Windows 8 Style App.  I have implemented ISupportIncrementalLoading and when the user scrolls the paging works great.

The problem that I'm having is when a user does a second search.  I apparently don't know how to get the LoadMoreItemsAsync to fire again.  I've tried the following:

1) Clear the underlying collection that is Observable and supports ISupportIncrementalLoading.  This clears all items from screen so I know it is bound properly.

2) Replace the underlying collection instance entirely that implements ISupportIncrementalLoading and raise INotifyPropertyChanged so the view knows the property was changed.  This also, clears all the items from the screen.

However, the LoadMoreItemsAsync doesn't want to fire after clearing or replacing the underlying collection instance.  My hunch is that the UI doesn't think it needs to Load any more, but since I've clear all the items it should want to load more.

I have verified that the HasMoreItems property is set to true.

If it would help, regrettably, you can see the error in production if you download FlixPicks from the Windows 8 store.  The steps to reproduce are:

1. Search using windows search contract
2. Notice paging works From the Search page
3. Search again.
4. Notice all items are cleared. (At this point the LoadMoreItemsAsync is not firing)

Thanks for any advice you can provide!

Comment: I just created a repro which seems to work fine. It's very simple, so probably something is being lost there. Can you take a look and try to see what's different? https://www.box.com/s/ddr8138khigwe6n78i4b

Comment: Hi Shahar, Thanks so much for the sample.  Your sample does work just fine.  I have adjusted it a bit so that it is not working anymore.  I am using a GridView instead of a list view and I adjusted the width of each item.  If you would be so kind, could you take a look at the adjusted code base.  In order to reproduce you don't scroll at all you have to be all the way to the left and then hit switch or clear.  If you scroll to the right at all it works.  https://www.box.com/s/9oe4miksi4yeyhat6rwo  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely looks like a bug. To solve this, add the following line after resetting your collection (in any of the cases):

```
gv.LoadMoreItemsAsync();
```

You can probably inherit from the control and create some overrides that will do this automatically:

Comment: Thanks. Technically this works but creates a mess when using a ViewModel because I don't have direct access to the two controls that bind to the collection.  I hacked it up for now.  I pass in an Action to my ViewModel which gets called in the view model then the Action has access to the controls.  I also had to deal with another issue.  I was getting an exception in some cases.  Seem like a timing issue.  For now, I just wait for 1 second and if there are not results yet then I force the call to the LoadMoreItemsAsync.  I added retry logic around it just incase 1 sec wasn't enough.  Ugh.

Comment: One of those "I need to shower" fixes. Fixing it in the control may be better. I'll look into it when/if I have time and put it on my blog/here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older issue, but I also encountered it and thought others may benefit from an MVVM approach to resolving it. My fix was, after resetting the collection, load a single item into the collection.

```
private async Task ResetCollectionAsync()
{
    Clear();
    await LoadMoreItemsAsync(1);
}
```

The collection is emptied and a single item is re-added. The `GridView`/`ListView` control detects the `CollectionChanged` event and re-queries `HasMoreItems` to determine whether to load additional data.

This behaviour is baked into [IncrementalLoadingCollection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UniversalWindowsPlatformToolkit.IncrementalLoadingCollection/) (v1.0.1), which also supports filtering and sorting functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reviving an old question, but I found a solution when none of the previous answers worked for me.

```
myCollection = new MyIncrementalLoadingCollection();
myListView.ItemSource = myCollection; //This is what I was missing!
```

Since I wanted the list view to refresh every time the page was navigated to, this was my end result.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    _logItems = new CommandLogIncrementalLoadingCollection();
    logListBox.ItemsSource = _logItems;
}
```